# Google Sheets FILTER formula greater than TODAY()

Tags: date, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want to filter the responses to a Google Form, so as to view only the rows with dates greater than Today() in Column I.

I'm using:

```
=filter(dates!A:J; dates!I:I > TODAY())
```

But no rows are being filtered out.

I'm suspecting that the arrayformula in Column I is causing the issue.
This arrayformula creates the date i'm trying to filter from columns B,C and D

demo file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BOuyQAGh4rVFfk8yL5zcuJBUFXPtOdAZz14JSr66AtE/edit?usp=sharing

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(dates!A:J; dates!I:I*1 >= TODAY())
```

[image]

Comment: This is not working when I put this formula on `Data Validation` dialog box.

Comment: @FaizanMubasher ofc not. in datavalidation you are expected to insert such formulae which output is boolean.